# Python os.listdir fails with FileNotFoundError when directory exists

Tags: python-3.x, windows, filesystems

I have the following code:

```
def handle_empty_directories(dir):
    if os.path.exists(dir):
        shouter.shout("%s exists" % dir)
    else:
       shouter.shout("%s doesn't exists" % dir)
    entries = os.listdir(dir)
    if entries == []:
        open(os.path.join(dir, Commiter.hed_file), "w").close()
    else:
        if (len(entries) > 1) and (Commiter.hed_file in entries):
            os.remove(os.path.join(dir, Commiter.hed_file))
        for entry in entries:
            if entry not in Commiter.hed_ignore:
                full_entry = os.path.join(dir, entry)
                if (os.path.isdir(full_entry)):
                    Commiter.handle_empty_directories(full_entry)
```

Occasionally, the call to `os.listdir(dir)` fails with `FileNotFoundError` even though the `os.path.exists(dir)` call says it exists:

```
08:57:56 - C:\r2g-wd\sport-6.0.5\SBS\SBS\Light\bin\com\ibm\ArtifactTechnology\ABS\ArtifactBroker exists
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "migration.py", line 169, in <module>
    migrate()
  File "migration.py", line 80, in migrate
    rtc.acceptchangesintoworkspace(rtc.getchangeentriestoaccept(changeentries, history))
  File "c:\Users\GeoffAlexander\Documents\Nirvana\RTC2Git\git-repositories\rtc2git-migration-tool\rtcFunctions.py", line 304, in acceptchangesintoworkspace
    Commiter.handle_empty_directories(os.getcwd())
  File "c:\Users\GeoffAlexander\Documents\Nirvana\RTC2Git\git-repositories\rtc2git-migration-tool\gitFunctions.py", line 126, in handle_empty_directories
    Commiter.handle_empty_directories(full_entry)
  File "c:\Users\GeoffAlexander\Documents\Nirvana\RTC2Git\git-repositories\rtc2git-migration-tool\gitFunctions.py", line 126, in handle_empty_directories
    Commiter.handle_empty_directories(full_entry)
  File "c:\Users\GeoffAlexander\Documents\Nirvana\RTC2Git\git-repositories\rtc2git-migration-tool\gitFunctions.py", line 126, in handle_empty_directories
    Commiter.handle_empty_directories(full_entry)
  [Previous line repeated 6 more times]
  File "c:\Users\GeoffAlexander\Documents\Nirvana\RTC2Git\git-repositories\rtc2git-migration-tool\gitFunctions.py", line 116, in handle_empty_directories
    entries = os.listdir(dir)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\r2g-wd\\sport-6.0.5\\SBS\\SBS\\Light\\bin\\com\\ibm\\ArtifactTechnology\\ABS\\ArtifactBroker'
```

How can this happen?  I'm running Python 3.7.2 64-bit on Windows 10.

Comment: Note that the underlying Windows error is `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` (3), not `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` (2). This means the problem in the example is with a path component prior to "ArtifactBroker".

Comment: Style note: an empty list has a false boolean value, so the idiomatic test is `not entries` instead of `entries == []`.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely a race condition. There is a period of time between testing if a directory exists, and then doing something to it, in which it can be deleted by another process.

The usual way to avoid this is to just try the action, and be ready for it to fail, e.g.:

```
try:
  os.listdir(x)
except FileNotFoundError:
  # log and stop here
```

Comment: This is not a race condition in my case.  The directory exists before and after the failure.

Comment: Either way, do you get the same behaviour if you switch to a try/except model?

Comment: Wrapping the failing calls in try/except worked!!!  I no longer get the spurious FileNotFound exceptions.  I'm still not sure why I need to wrap the calls in try/except to prevent the spurious FileNotFound exceptions.  I've open Python Issue 36243 (https://bugs.python.org/issue36243?@ok_message=issue%2036243%20type%20edited%20ok&@template=item) to get a better understanding of what's going on.